# load tab delimited data into mysql

Tags: mysql, load, csv

I need to load a text file tabDelimited/csv directly into mysql as table. I am following the page (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/loading-tables.html) for doing the same.

### testfile.txt

```
field1,field2
"abc",1
"def",2
"ghi",3
```

However, I keep getting the following message:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'testfile.txt' INTO TABLE myTable IGNORE 1 LINES;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.myTable' doesn't exist
```

I see that 'load' can be used only after creating the table. So the error is expected. I have multiple files and I need to avoid creating tables one by one. Is there any other way to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the table before you insert data into it.

If you have multiple files, create the table once, then append data using several `LOAD DATA INFILE` calls.

MySQL cannot automatically determine the schema of your data from a CSV file. Creating the table is essential for establishing the data type of the columns and any indexes or keys.

Comment: I have multiple files and I need to avoid this step. However, I was looking for any alternate way.

Comment: What do you mean "avoid this step"? Do you expect MySQL to magically create tables for you based on a schema you haven't provided?

Comment: It sounds like he's looking for a "Text to DDL" tool like the one that jsfiddle.com uses.

Comment: Automatically defining the DDL from text is not a very reliable mechanism, jsfiddle.com often guesses wrong when it does this. It's OK for a debugging tool, but totally inappropriate for a production database.

Comment: Ok, It seems I will need to write code to do it automatically. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have the table created yet.

Just an example that you can bend to your needs.
create table if not exists (field1 VARCHAR(3), field2 INTEGER);

Full documentation on create table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html